# Android DB in app-specific folder vs external folder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have an Android app that writes data to a db. Initially, when we started, we stored the db in an app-specific folder (something like /storage/org.domain.app/db/db.sync and so on). Things worked with no issues. However, the issue was that  this DB would get wiped out everytime we reinstall the app.

We therefore moved the DB to a different folder outside the app. (Now the path is something like /storage/data/db/db.sync). Now, if we reinstall the app, we still have the old DB entries. However, now reading and writing to the DB is a lot lot slower.

I am not sure if this slowness is because the amount of data has shot up. Since the data is now persistent across multiple reinstalls.

I suspect this could also be because the DB is now in a folder external to the app. To rule this out, I setup the DB in an app specific folder and intend to copy the entire DB from some previous tests (that contains lot more data - the amount of data which caused the DB access to slow down). However, I am unable to do so.

Some questions:
1. I am not able to actually access the folder where the DB is setup. The folder is created in Context.MODE_PRIVATE mode. Therefore, only the app itself can access it. I tried changing it to MODE.WORLD_READABLE. However, this is deprecated and throws an exception while using it. Is there a way to make this folder easily editable?

2. I also tried accessing the DB from Device file explorer in Android studio. I opened the existing DB  (db.sync file) and just copy-pasted the large DB I already have. However, it looks like this method does not allow us to copy or even display more than 400 KB of information. The DB I have is around 60-70 MB. Hence this approach did not work either. 
   Is there a way I can edit the db.sync file?
3. Does DB being in a folder external to the app make it slower? Esp when there are too many entries. In my case, certain search operations happen via a local cache and happens in a giffy. However, we also need to log some stuff to the DB and that takes forever. I figured this out by adding timer logs in the code.
4. Anything else, I could do to identify if the DB path is causing the issue?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Reinstalling an app does NOT wipe the db, unless you uninstall it first.  And even then you can soft uninstall it via adb so that it keeps its data directories.

Comment: `/storage/org.domain.app/db/db.sync` That is an impossible path on an Android device. And certainly not an app specific folder. `/storage/data/db/db.sync)` is impossible too.

Comment: Please post actual paths as now it does not make sense.